# Remote Desktop microphone forwarding on Win7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, audio, remote-desktop

I'd like to use the microphone forwarding over RDP on Win7 Pro. Unfortunately this is only available on Enterprise and Ultimate editions. Do you know of any workaround for this?

I'l like those workarounds to be free if possible

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to enable it by changing the value of this registry subkey:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\fDisableAudioCapture
```

To enable audio redirection change its value to `0`.

More information can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2020918).

Comment: The key didn't change anything. Moreover the page you linked says : "Note The Audio Recording Redirection feature is not available in Windows Professional edition."